# ToAscii/ToUnicode in a keyboard hook destroys dead keys

Tags: windows, unicode, diacritics, keyboard-hook

It seems that if you call `ToAscii()` or `ToUnicode()` while in a global WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook, and a dead-key is pressed, it will be 'destroyed'.

For example, say you've configured your input language in Windows as Spanish, and you want to type an accented letter **á** in a program. Normally, you'd press the single-quote key (the dead key), then the letter "a", and then on the screen an accented **á** would be displayed, as expected.

But this doesn't work if you call `ToAscii()` or `ToUnicode()` in a low-level keyboard hook function. It seems that the dead key is destroyed, and so no accented letter **á** shows up on screen. Removing a call to the above functions resolves the issue... but unfortunately, I need to be able to call those functions.

I Googled for a while, and while a lot of people seemed to have this issue, no good solution was provided.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** I'm calling `ToAscii()` to convert the virtual-key code and scan code received in my [LowLevelKeyboardProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985%28VS.85%29.aspx) hook function into the resulting character that will be displayed on screen for the user.

I tried `MapVirtualKey(kbHookData->vkCode, 2)`, but this isn't as "complete" a function as `ToAscii()`; for example, if you press Shift + 2, you'll get '2', not '@' (or whatever Shift + 2 will produce for the user's keyboard layout/language).

`ToAscii()` is perfect... until a dead-key is pressed.

**EDIT2:** Here's the hook function, with irrelevant info removed:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboard_LL_hook_func(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbHookData = (LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;
    BYTE keyboard_state[256];

    if (code < 0) {
        return CallNextHookEx(keyHook, code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    WORD wCharacter = 0;

    GetKeyboardState(&keyboard_state);
    int ta = ToAscii((UINT)kbHookData->vkCode, kbHookData->scanCode,
                     keyboard_state, &wCharacter, 0);

    /* If ta == -1, a dead-key was pressed. The dead-key will be "destroyed"
     * and you'll no longer be able to create any accented characters. Remove
     * the call to ToAscii() above, and you can then create accented characters. */

    return CallNextHookEx(keyHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for the call to ToUnicode().  Where do you get the lpKeyState parameter?

Comment: @jdigital: Well, I'm personally calling ToAscii, but I've read it happens with ToUnicode, too. My call is basically ToAscii(kbHookData->vkCode, kbHookData->scanCode, GetKeyboardState(), &lpchar, 0) in the WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook function. When the ToAscii call returns -1, this means a dead key was pressed... and the dead key is 'destroyed' as I explained above.

Comment: I deleted my answer, it was completely incorrect based on the assumption that you were referring to c-runtime functions to convert strings rather than Win32 apis to convert scancodes... sorry.

Comment: I would help a lot if you could describe the purpose of doing this, we may find other solutions for your problem.

Comment: @Sorin: See the edit to my original question for more info. :-)

Comment: Can you post your entire hook function code? The problem could hide not in the ToAscii itself, but in the surrounding hook logic. Also, as a wild guess, try `SetLastError(0)` at the end of the hook function.

Comment: @atzz: I just added the hook function code. I believe it is ToAscii() that's the problem, because if I don't call it, the problem doesn't occur. Thanks for the SetLastError(0) suggestion, but unfortunately that didn't do anything.

Comment: You're missing the initialization for keyboard_state.

Comment: @jdigital: Oops. Fixed. GetKeyboardState() was called in my real code, though.

Comment: Did you find any solution_

Answer (score 4):

It is [known](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex) that `ToUnicode()` and its older counterpart `ToAscii()` can change keyboard state of the current thread and thus mess with dead keys and ALT+NUMPAD keystrokes:

> As ToUnicodeEx translates the virtual-key code, it also changes the
> state of the kernel-mode keyboard buffer. This state-change affects
> dead keys, ligatures, alt+numpad key entry, and so on. It might also
> cause undesired side-effects if used in conjunction with
> TranslateMessage (which also changes the state of the kernel-mode
> keyboard buffer).

To avoid that you can **do your ToUnicode() call in a separate thread** (it will have a separate keyboard state) or use a special flag in `wFlags` param that is documented in [ToUnicode() docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex):

> If bit 2 is set, keyboard state is not changed (Windows 10, version
> 1607 and newer)

Or you can prepare sc->char mapping table beforehand and update it on `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` language change event.

I think it should work with `ToAscii()` too but better not use this old ANSI codepage-dependant method. Use `ToUnicode()` API instead that can even return [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligature_(writing)) and [UTF-16 surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) - if keyboard layout have them. [Some do](https://kbdlayout.info/features/ligatures).

See [Asynchronous input vs synchronous input, a quick introduction](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130604-00/?p=4173)
 for the reason behind this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, even if it is only valid as of Windows 10. It's definitely the way to go for anyone looking for a solution now.

Comment: The part about a “**call in a separate thread**” is wrong.  Even doing it in a separate application would not make it “non-destructive”.  (Try: **(A)** open two applications (may be different!) with the same keyboad layout chosen.  **(B)** Type a prefix key (=deadkey) in one.  **(D)** Switch to the other application, and type a followup key — you would get the result of combining the deadkey+key.)

Comment: To add insult to injury, you can even add: **(C)** Switch to a different keyboard layout (in the first application), and type something,  (May include dead keys too!)  This would not change the result in the second application.

Comment: The part about the advantages of `ToUnicode` to `ToAscii` also seems wrong.  AFAIK, the only difference is the limitation to `ASCII` range (and a possible `CP` conversion — do not remember…)

Comment: See [my discussion of non-destructive `ToUnicode` calls](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#The-bullet-proof-method); a very short summary is at the end of this section.  It was possible even before the bit `0x04` was introduced — with minor limitations/complications.  (Compare with the 4th note in [details of input-by-number](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#Keyboard-input-on-Windows,-Part-II:-The-semantic-of-ToUnicode()).)

Comment: I added an answer (with essentially the comment above as content).

Answer (score 3):

Quite an old thread. Unfortunately it didn't contain the answer I was looking for and none of the answers seemed to work properly. I finally solved the problem by checking the [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) of the `MapVirtualKey` function, before calling `ToUnicode` / `ToAscii`. Seems to be working like a charm:

```
if(!(MapVirtualKey(kbHookData->vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR)>>(sizeof(UINT)*8-1) & 1)) {
    ToAscii((UINT)kbHookData->vkCode, kbHookData->scanCode,
        keyboard_state, &wCharacter, 0);
}
```

Quoting MSDN on the return value of `MapVirtualKey`, if  `MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR` is used:

> [...] Dead keys (diacritics) are indicated by setting the top bit of the return value. [...]

Comment: could you please elaborate more? I don't get your code, what if you don't enter the if()? doing nothing?

Comment: In case it's not entering the if, the current key pressed is a dead key. Depending on what you would like to achieve, you can react to it, or simply ignore it, in case you would like to only listen to non-dead key presses. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I got it

Comment: Does not work  for dead chars that use "ALT GR" key for example (right ALT, as it produces "CTRL + ALT" key message). Exemple of french keyboard layout trying to add accent this accent over a letter : ` = ì

Comment: This is wrong on at least two counts.  First, `MapVirtualKey` inspects the binding of the physical key *only on the “unshifted”-“un-`AltGr`ayed” level*.  Second, even if “the current level” is “unshifted”-“un-`AltGr`ayed”, the fact that **by default** this key is a dead key tells us nothing about how this key behaves **now**.  If it is pressed *after another dead key*, it may be “again a dead key”, or it may terminate a “key chord”.

Answer (score 2):

1. stop using ToAscii() and use ToUncode()
2. remember that ToUnicode may return you nothing on dead keys - this is why they are called dead keys.
3. Any key will have a scancode or a virtual key code but not necessary a character.

You shouldn't combine the buttons with characters - assuming that any key/button has a text representation (Unicode) is wrong.

So:

- for **input text** use the *characters* reported by Windows
- for checking **button pressed** (ex. games) use *scancodes* or *virtual keys* (probably virtual keys are better).
- for **keyboard shortcuts** use *virtual key* codes.

Comment: I tried using ToUnicode(), but the same thing happens... the "dead-key" is destroyed, and so a double-accent is shown when I press the accent key, and I can't make any accented letters. Uninstalling the hook immediately fixes the issue. Not calling ToAscii() or ToUnicode() immediately fixes the issue as well.

Comment: Try to make a copy of keyboard state structure in order to prevent Windows from altering the original one.

Comment: This is almost completely unrelated to the question (except `ToAscii` being last-millenium) and wrong on many counts.  For example, `ToUnicode` ***would*** return the information about the dead key (although making it non-destructive is tricky — see my answer).  Second, there is no way to copy/affect the state of the keyboard layout *except* through `ToUnicode(Ex)`/`ToAscii`.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue while creating a key logger in C# and none of the above answers worked for me.

After a deep blog searching, I stumbled across this [keyboard listener](https://gist.github.com/akimsko/2011327) which handles dead keys perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full code which covers dead keys and shortcut keys using ALT + NUMPAD, basically a full implementation of a TextField input handling:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ToUnicode(uint virtualKeyCode, uint scanCode, byte[] keyboardState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)] StringBuilder receivingBuffer, int bufferSize, uint flags);

    private StringBuilder _pressCharBuffer = new StringBuilder(256);
    private byte[] _pressCharKeyboardState = new byte[256];

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        var handled = false;

        if (m.Msg == 0x0100 || m.Msg == 0x0102)
        {

            bool isShiftPressed = (ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0;
            bool isControlPressed = (ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0;
            bool isAltPressed = (ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) != 0;
            bool isAltGrPressed = (ModifierKeys & Keys.RMenu) != 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
                _pressCharKeyboardState[i] = 0;

            if (isShiftPressed)
                _pressCharKeyboardState[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = 0xff;

            if (isAltGrPressed)
            {
                _pressCharKeyboardState[(int)Keys.ControlKey] = 0xff;
                _pressCharKeyboardState[(int)Keys.Menu] = 0xff;
            }

            if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
                _pressCharKeyboardState[(int)Keys.CapsLock] = 0xff;

            Char chr = (Char)0;

            int ret = ToUnicode((uint)m.WParam.ToInt32(), 0, _pressCharKeyboardState, _pressCharBuffer, 256, 0);

            if (ret == 0)
                chr = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(m.WParam.ToInt32())[0];
            if (ret == -1)
                ToUnicode((uint)m.WParam.ToInt32(), 0, _pressCharKeyboardState, _pressCharBuffer, 256, 0);
            else if (_pressCharBuffer.Length > 0)
                chr = _pressCharBuffer[0];

            if (m.Msg == 0x0102 && Char.IsWhiteSpace(chr))
                chr = (Char)0;


            if (ret >= 0 && chr > 0)
            {

            //DO YOUR STUFF using either "chr" as special key (UP, DOWN, etc..) 
            //either _pressCharBuffer.ToString()(can contain more than one character if dead key was pressed before)
            //and don't forget to set the "handled" to true, so nobody else can use the message afterwards

            }
        }

        return handled;
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong on many counts.  (I do not know what `0x100` and `0x102` mean, so cannot comment in detail.)  For example, for doubling deadkeys, see my comment to `Blue eyes`’s answer.  For example, this code indiscriminately mixes `VK_`-codes and characters.  For example, [`ToUnicode` needs to process `KeyUp` events for `Alt-NUMPAD` input](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#Keyboard-input-on-Windows,-Part-II:-The-semantic-of-ToUnicode()).   For example, the keyboard layout may distinguish handed-variants of `Ctrl`/`Alt`.  Etc…  (I added a correct answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Call 'ToAscii' function twice for a correct processing of dead-key, like in:

```
int ta = ToAscii((UINT)kbHookData->vkCode, kbHookData->scanCode,
                 keyboard_state, &wCharacter, 0);
int ta = ToAscii((UINT)kbHookData->vkCode, kbHookData->scanCode,
                 keyboard_state, &wCharacter, 0);
If (ta == -1)
 ...
```

Comment: This just 'kills' the dead key for me. E.g. 'ë' becomes 'e', but pressing a dead key twice still gives e.g. ¨¨

Comment: Essentially, what you are saying is that a triple press of a dead key gives the same result as a simple press — provided one discards the string resulting from the second press.  For many keys on many keyboard layouts this may work.  However, this would not work for important dead keys on many layouts.  (For example, think of how a `Compose` key may operate.  On my layouts, double-`Compose` enters “another flavor of composing”.) — I wrote an answer with the correct approaches to this important question.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `ToAscii` or `ToUnicode` twice is the answer.
I found this and converted it for Delphi, and it works!

```
cnt:=ToUnicode(VirtualKey, KeyStroke, KeyState, chars, 2, 0);
cnt:=ToUnicode(VirtualKey, KeyStroke, KeyState, chars, 2, 0); //yes call it twice
```

Comment: Its a little better as my '^' char is displayed only after the second key press, as expected, but doesn't work because the accent doesn't go over the letter as it should produce 'ô', but only produces 'o'

Comment: Actually your answer is the same as @Blue eyes below :https://stackoverflow.com/a/3625039/2165463

Comment: I addressed the problems with this approach in a comment to the `Blue eyes` answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before introduction of the bit `0x04` for the `wFlag` argument, [doing non-destructive `ToUnicode` calls](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#The-bullet-proof-method) was a tricky topic.  The referenced text discusses it (and the current state) in a lot of details.  (Sometimes I suspect that it may have been this discussion which led to implementation of `0x04`…  But it [was also suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2605828/9106292).)

A very short summary “of the old way” is at the end of the referenced section: use `wFlags=0x01|0x02` and detect/implement input-by-number yourself.  (Compare with the 4th note in [details of input-by-number](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#Keyboard-input-on-Windows,-Part-II:-The-semantic-of-ToUnicode()).)

Answer (score -1):

I copy the vkCode in a queue and do the conversion from another thread

```
@HOOKPROC
def keyHookKFunc(code,wParam,lParam):
    global gkeyQueue
    gkeyQueue.append((code,wParam,kbd.vkCode))
    return windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(0,code,wParam,lParam)
```

This has the advantage of not delaying key processing by the os

Comment: In addition to having nothing to do with the original question, this has a disadvantage of being wrong.  (For example, `ToUnicode` has state, so calls should happen in the correct order.)

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
byte[] keyState = new byte[256];

//Remove this if using
//GetKeyboardState(keyState); 

//Add only the Keys you want
keysDown[(int)Keys.ShiftKey] = 0x80; // SHIFT down
keysDown[(int)Keys.Menu] = 0x80; // ALT down
keysDown[(int)Keys.ControlKey] = 0x80; // CONTROL down
  
//ToAscii should work fine         
if (ToAscii(myKeyboardStruct.VirtualKeyCode, myKeyboardStruct.ScanCode, keyState, inBuffer, myKeyboardStruct.Flags) == 1)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with the original question.  Second, this will work in very limited set of situations only.  (See my comment to `Stefan Pintilie`’s approach — which is much more elaborate so covers a bit more ground than yours…)