# How can I use ToUnicode without breaking dead key support?

Tags: c++, c, windows, unicode, keyboard

A similar question has already been asked, so I'm not going to waste time re-explaining it, an existing discussion can be found here:
[ToAscii/ToUnicode in a keyboard hook destroys dead keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964614/toascii-tounicode-in-a-keyboard-hook-destroys-dead-keys)

The reason I'm posting a new question however is that I seem to have come across a 'solution', but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

This blog post seems to propose a solution to the problem of ToUnicode killing dead-key support:
http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/19/355870.aspx

However I'm not sure how to implement the suggested solution. A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

To be clear, the part I'm referring to is this:

> There are two ways to work around this:
>
> 1) You can keep calling ToUnicode with the same info until it is cleared out and then call it one more time to put the state back where it was if you had never typed anything, or
>
> 2) You can load all of the keyboard info ahead of time and then when they type information you can look up in your own info cache what the keystrokes mean, without having to call APIs later.

I'm not quite sure how to do either of those things (keyboards and internationalization are far from my strong point), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first part of the answer is *entirely* information-free. However, the second part does make sense. `ToUnicode()` **should** have been a pure function, which merely acts as a lookup. However, it isn't. But you can call it repeatedly for all expected inputs, store those in your own lookup table and access that.

I'd recommend that Microsoft adds a `lookDontTouch` flag to the `wFlags` parameter; that would be a trivial non-breaking API fix.

Comment: but fixing the win32 API would be a dangerous precedent to set. Think of the amount of work they'd have ahead of them if they start down *that* path.

Comment: @jalf: I'm not sure if that's sarcastic. i18n/l10n of Windows is in active development. For this particular bit they probably don't want .Net code (keyboard handling is fairly low-level) so fixing the Win32 API is a reasonable proposal, possibly the only one.

Comment: Any chance of a code example to push me in the right direction? I'm embarrassed to say I'm still a little lost. Ugh, I hate this keyboard stuff so much. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be sarcastic. It's just that there's an awful lot of the Win32 API that could do with being fixed. :)

Comment: Actually no need to add something like a `lookDontTouch` flag. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37909846/1338417). Quoting MSDN on the return value of MapVirtualKey, if MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR is used: [...] Dead keys (diacritics) are indicated by setting the top bit of the return value. [...]

Comment: MapVirtualKey with MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR flag is broken for `A`..`Z` keys. Also it do not support ligatures. See my answer here.https://stackoverflow.com/a/72464584/1795050

Comment: Fast forward to 2016 and that lookDontTouch flag has been added to wFlags: If bit 2 is set, keyboard state is not changed (Windows 10, version 1607 and newer)

Comment: That flag sadly doesn't affect the kernel's Alt-Numpad buffer.

Comment: @gix: can you please be more precise?  Do you say that its behavior is kind-of identical to [using the “always-was-there” flag `0x02` with the bit for `KeyUp` raised in `lParam`](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#The-bullet-proof-method)? (See the note at end of the referenced section — and also “the rest of this chapter” .)

Comment: Unfortunately, what you call “the second part” is not only “does ***NOT*** make sense, but is a complete disaster in its effect on the landscape of applications on Windows.  (See my answer.)

Comment: @gix: And another question, just for double-checking: when testing `Alt-NUMPAD` input, you passed **the whole 16-bit scancodes**, including `KBDEXT` and `KBDBREAK` flags, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you broaden your search to include [key logging](http://www.docdroppers.org/wiki/index.php?title=Writing_Keyloggers), you might get some answers. The method presented in the link is extremely cumbersome compared to `ToUnicode`, but it works. It evolves around finding the current active keyboard layout from the registry and then manually load and parse the proper DLL.

As a note of warning, I've seen the loading part fail miserably on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: I ran some quick tests and it seems that the code does indeed fail under x64 builds of Windows unless the code is compiled natively for x64.

Ugh, this is all such a pain in the ass.

Thanks though, this looks to be an interesting option.

Answer (score 0):

This flag from `MSalters`’s answer is nowadays present (`0x04`).

For a short summary of what can be done without this flag I refer to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964614/toascii-tounicode-in-a-keyboard-hook-destroys-dead-keys/78173420#78173420)

——————————————————————————

In general, the discussed here Kaplan’s approach “of loading the DLL and parsing the info” led to innumerable collection of buggy programs!  For example, I suspect that Firefox and Chrome are doing this — so I need to spend incalculatable amount of time fighting with the resulting bugs…  (With Firefox, some of them were fixed — after my bug reports, but a lot of others remain…)

The reason for this is that it “assumes a **correct** parsing” of the content of the DLL. — Which, in particular, assumes a complete knowledge of how Windows do it!  Given the girth of knowledge about this (but see [my descriptions](https://metacpan.org/dist/UI-KeyboardLayout/view/lib/UI/KeyboardLayout.pm#Keyboard-input-on-Windows,-Part-II:-The-semantic-of-ToUnicode())) — and the ability of programmers to write bullet-proof code: one gets the “expected result” .