# Keyboard hook: change the key code

Tags: c, windows, keyboard-hook

I did hook the keyboard of some process. Now I need to change the key message sent to the process.

For example: from lowercase to uppercase and opposite.

How can I do this?

Comment: What platform? What API? Any code? What you tried and failed?

Comment: There's an April's fool next year too :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548932/keyboard-hook-changes-the-behavior-of-keys

Comment: platform Windows . API windows too. I write in C. not c++

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function prototype is as follows:
`LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UING uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )`,
the value of your letter is inside wParam. Assuming pure ASCII keyboard input, then you can use the following:

```
short newKeyCode = (char)wParam;
if (uMsg == WM_CHAR || uMsg == WM_SYSCHAR)
if (newKeyCode - 'a' < 26) {
  newKeyCode = newKeyCode - 'a' + 'A';
} else {
  newKeyCode = newKeyCode - 'A' + 'a';
}
```

Of course, if you're on a Windows system beyond 2000 (and thus running on the NT architecture), wParam will be a Unicode value (and UTF-16, as is the Windows convention), so your program may have to fiddle with this to get it into a nice state, but otherwise this should be all you need.